# What Event IDs are generated in Windows server when changes are made to the login service dialog?

Tags: service, windows-event-log, windows-service

Is there a way to turn on logs for when changes are made to a credentials for a service like the one below?

[image: SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) Properties (Local Computer)]

Comment: This is a completely valid question by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The subinacl tool should let you do that, see this blog article that talks about that: https://www.eventsentry.com/blog/2007/11/setting-service-permissions-wi.html

However, keep in mind that subinacl isn't easily available anymore, but the built-in icacls.exe should be able to do the same exact thing.

Coincidentally, the product referenced in that post (EventSentry) does that natively, and can generate an alert any time a service property such as the user, startup type, binary etc is changed.

Comment: That's a bit dated tool for changing the permissions. SetACL probably works better. For just auditing changes to that value, you could enable registry auditing for the service(s).